# Debian broke after installing xfce

Tags: linux, debian, xfce

I have Parrot OS(debian 9) installed in my computer. I als did have installed the mate and bspwm desktop enviroments. Solving a technical issue with xrdp I accidentally installed the xfce desktop enviroment. And after a restart any of my desktops enviroments aren't loading, neither bspwm mate or xfce. When I boot the Parrot OS I get asked for my password, and I typed correctly but then I enter a black screen and after 3-4 seconds I get redirected to the previous screen.

Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: does the login screen present a choice of desktop managers?

Comment: Yes I do get the choice

Answer (score 0):

Before logging in, press `ctrl` + `alt` + `F1` (or any other f-key) so you get to the text based command line, from which you can log in and manually unistall xfce.

Also consider checking the logs with `journalctl -xe` and `syslog`.

Comment: Thank you UnderCoverdog I could manually login usin crtl+alt+f5 and I managed to uninstall xfce. However the problem still remains, I can't enter bspwm or mate. I have undone all the changes since this problem apeared but didn't work. I am completly lost. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check the logs `journalctl -xe` and `syslog`, there are also some more, but I cant remember them

Comment: Thank you again UndercoverDog, I was finally able to recover my Parrot OS!!! Using journalctl -xe I found that there were some binaries missing and some miscondigured file properties, I fixed that I and all returned to work fine